# not all RAM recognised (on 64bit CPU)

Tags: ubuntu, memory, ram, 64bit

I've installed Ubuntu server 16.04 (64bit) on a [Dell fx160](http://www.dell.com/us/dfb/p/optiplex-fx160/pd) thin client (has an atom 230 processor). This device has two sticks of ram in it, 2 GB each.

When I execute `lshw` I see that it correctly recognises that the two sticks have 2 GB each. When I run `free` however, only 3 GB (3079672 kB) of memory is reported as being available.

Removing either of these sticks causes `free` to report exactly 2 GB, but when inserted together only 3 GB remains.

I searched around a lot, but unfortunately I remain clueless as to what can cause this and how I can solve this.

Has anyone had a similar problem in the past?

Comment: What does /proc/meminfo say?

Comment: The manual says up to 1gb may be reserved on a 32 bit operating system. Could there be a bios setting that is holding the extra 1gb anyway?

Comment: @Bex sorry, I meant kB.
/proc/meminfo says same: 3.079.672 kB
checked and double checked the bios but couldn't find anything (set the video memory to its minimum of 64MB), and it is a 64bit install.